# Must exposed pad (EP) for thermal dissipation be connected to ground for testing on breadboard

Tags: integrated-circuit, ground

I am testing a [MCP8063](http://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/en/MCP8063), 8-lead 4 mm x 4 mm DFN package with exposed pad.

I have it deadbug to fit onto a breadboard. I have yet to get it to run a motor. Must the EP be grounded in order to test the IC chip and if so, how much surface area of the pad must be grounded to be sufficient? Also, as inferred, this particular chip is not mounted on its own pcb for testing, hence EP not grounded, how should I go about grounding the EP as it is now just hovering over the breadboard?

Comment: What does the data sheet tell you.Surely you have to read it to understand how to interface to it so you don't really have a good excuse.

Comment: My question was twofold. I am aware that datasheet says connect to ground because EP is used for thermal dissipation. I figured it should, but asked to be sure anyway. It was a lead up question to how to ground EP with my current cheap and crude method of testing an IC chip since it was clearly not working without a grounded EP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the internal design of the part. I have seen parts where the exposed pad MUST be connected to ground and others where it isn't necessary for proper operation. (Though ground is a convenient thermal sink.)

In this case the data sheet specifies that it should be connected to ground, so I would go with that.  If you want to breadboard without a PCB (which isn't really advisable) you could solder a heavy gauge wire to the pad and ground it.  That should help with thermals too, but you will have a thermal problem if you want to run the part anywhere near its limits.

Comment: I'll try the heavy gauge wire. I'm testing the chip for a quick compatibility check with a motor I have before incorporating it into a comprehensive pcb design.